# How to add Auto-increment field for existing records in mongodb using mongoose-sequence?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-sequence

I managed to add auto-increment field for my mongodb collection. But I want to add auto-increment field to existing records.

I'm trying to add **project_id** auto-increment field to my **projects** collection.

But, I already have around 100+ records in my collection.

Can anyone help with the above problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize the `project_id` field, you can use `$setWindowFields` with the `$documentNumber` operator and merge the collection into itself to add the field. The following sample from [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cR0-lldMc-A) provides an overview:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "project_id": {
          "$documentNumber": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      project_id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: "collection"
  }
])
```

The `sort` parameter defines the order of documents, in the sample, the documents are sorted by `_id` in ascending order. `output` adds fields to the document that are calculated for the window. As we have not provided a `partitionBy` and `window` parameters, all documents are included in the same window and the `$documentNumber` function adds an incrementing number to the documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "project_id": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "project_id": 2
  }
]
```

The `$project` stage removes redundant fields before `$merge` adds the fields to the existing documents. Please test the sample before running the merge.